# While adding same image 2 times from imageview firebase storage override previous and makes 2 different url for same image

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

I have make a ImageView to add images to firebase storage it works fine when I restart the activity but without restarting activity when I upload first image to firebase storage it add successfully but when I upload the same image another time it override previous image and generate new URL, both previous and new URL contains same image and image is only one in firebase storage for both URL the problem is when I delete image from any one URL it delete image and then second URL gets empty and it does not contain image.

Comment: If you are uploading as a file, you can try to change the file name before uploading.

Comment: how can I change the filename I have generate random UUID

Comment: and also how to change random UUID without restarting activity

Comment: What is the exact code that you are using?

Comment: firebasestorage =
            FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReference(
                    Images" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                )